# Recovering a MySQL database from a slave server

Tags: mysql, database-replication

There's a fair amount of background info.  I will get to the question near the end of this.

I have a MySQL replication setup with one master and two slaves.  We had a power problem with one of the slaves, which led to the database getting corrupted.

Because the master server and one of the slaves are running on Solaris 10 with the MySQL database on a zfs filesystem, we have a snapshot backup script that performs a very specific task:

- FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK
- SHOW MASTER STATUS

  - record file/position to a file in the data directory.
- Take a snapshot of the data directory with zfs.
- UNLOCK TABLES

If there are no long-running queries, the entire process takes about a second.

I can use a snapshot created in this way on the master server, along with the recorded master file/position data, as a basis for complete database recovery on a slave.

The slave server that needs recovery is the slave that is NOT running on Solaris, it's on Linux with an ext4 filesystem.  I am copying the snapshot from the master, but it looks like it may take a week or more, because the master server is extremely busy and the rsync is not getting any disk I/O bandwidth.

I did a partial test copy from the other slave server, and transfer rates are MUCH better ... so now I would like to try recovering from that slave instead.

In preparation for this, I added a step to the snapshot script (after the SHOW MASTER STATUS) where it does "SHOW SLAVE STATUS" and records Relay_Master_Log_File as file and Exec_Master_Log_Pos as position.  I now have several snapshots on the slave server that contain this information.

**The burning question:** Is the "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK" command good enough to assure that the log replay information found in "SHOW SLAVE STATUS" is 100% coordinated with the filesystem snapshot, or would the script actually need to do STOP SLAVE before it records the slave status and makes the snapshot?

This is the version of mysql running on the Solaris master and slave servers:

/u01/mysql/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.67, for sun-solaris2.10 (sparc) using readline 5.1

Answer (score 0):

FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK is generally acceptable to use with SHOW SLAVE STATUS (much the same as you do SHOW MASTER STATUS) for purposes of determining the relevant binary log position.

You can also sortof skip that by relying on the information that is already on disk when you rsync, you do however have to watch out the the relay log index and files will have the wrong name because it is based on the slave hostname by default.  You can find that by renaming the files *and* renaming the references in the index, or jut using the same relay-log-name.

This document talks about that, but it's basically just doing the same thing:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-howto-additionalslaves.html

However.. if you use temporary tables much, you should make sure that none are currently open at the position you snapshot by checking Slave_open_temp_tables

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-features-temptables.html

Comment: The slave status does include the name of the *master* logfile that is currently being replayed onto the slave (presumably from the relay log).

I have now added a query to find out the value of Slave_open_temp_tables for each snapshot, and I then I can know whether that snapshot can be used effectively for recovery.  The snapshots are made once an hour, so there should be plenty of them.

My hope is that the flush and lock will ensure that all temporary tables are closed ... I guess we'll find out.

Comment: Additional detail: When I rsync the data directory to the slave I'm recovering, I will NOT copy any binary logs.  They aren't required, and they're huge.

Comment: Here is an example of the info that is now recorded on every snapshot into the slaveposition.log file:  
  
    snapshot 2015052318: file mysql-bin.009872, position 13252441  
    additional: mlf mysql-bin.009872, rlf mysql-relay-bin.020175  
    Slave_open_temp_tables: 0